# using python to parse colon (:) delimited string to an object

Tags: python

i have a string which is a return value of REST API (http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/REST) and is using colon seperated key/value pairs.

```
id: 123414
name: Peter
message: bla bla
  bla bla
```

How can i parse this string to an object? is there an existing python parser that i can use??

Here's the string that i want to parse:

```
'RT/3.8.8 200 Ok\n\nid: ticket/46863\nQueue: customer-test\nOwner: Nobody\nCreator: young.park\nSubject: testing\nStatus: new\nPriority: 0\nInitialPriority: 0\nFinalPriority: 0\nRequestors: superuser@meme.com\nCc:\nAdminCc:\nCreated: Mon Apr 25 15:50:27 2011\nStarts: Not set\nStarted: Not set\nDue: Not set\nResolved: Not set\nTold: Not set\nLastUpdated: Mon Apr 25 15:50:28 2011\nTimeEstimated: 0\nTimeWorked: 0\nTimeLeft: 0\nCF.{Severity}: \n\n'
```

Comment: Please define serialize. I don't think it means what you think it does.

Comment: Do you mean that you're looking for something to parse your returned data format into some type of object?

Comment: yes. I meant to say parsing to some type of object.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried to use to parse this object.  It's important to show your work and your understanding.

Comment: What you have shown is ambiguous. Please do `print repr(your_string))` and edit your question to show the result exactly -- if you need to abbreviate it, chop some out of the middle; don't chop the tail off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really need to say which REST api and provide a documentation reference.

Superficially, it doesn't look too hard:

```
# Look Ma, no imports!
>>> s = 'id: 1234\nname: Peter\nmessage: foo bar zot\nmsg2: tee:hee\n'
>>> dict(map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1)) for line in s.splitlines())
{'message': 'foo bar zot', 'msg2': 'tee:hee', 'id': '1234', 'name': 'Peter'}
```

But: (1) the documentation should point you at a parser (2) nothing is ever as easy as it seems from one simple example (see `tee:hee` above); if you decide on rolling your own, you should break the above one-liner up into multiple steps so that you can do some error checking (e.g. line.split() returns exactly 2 pieces).

**Update** after api reference was given:

At first glance, the website gives an enormous number of examples without actually stating what the format is. I suggest that you give it more than a glance; if that fails, ask the author/maintainer.

**Update 2** after actual example input given, and after comment "I just tried this and got crashed":

The code supplied was in response to the first (ambiguous) example input, in which all lines except the last contained a colon. It was accompanied by a suggestion that it should be done in pieces instead of a one-liner with especial mention of checking the result of `split(':', 1)`. What code did you use? What exactly does "got crashed" mean? Have you tried to work out for yourself what your problem was, and fix it?

What data did you feed it? Your long-awaited actual sample has colon-separated key:value lines *preceded by* a heading line and an empty line and followed by an empty line. These can be blissfully ignored by a trivial adjustment to the one-liner:

```
>>> print dict(map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1)) for line in s.splitlines()[2:-1])
{'Status': 'new', 'Resolved': 'Not set', 'CF.{Severity}': '',
'TimeLeft': '0', 'Creator': 'young.park', 'Cc': '', 'Starts': 'Not set',
'Created': 'Mon Apr 25 15:50:27 2011', 'Due': 'Not set',
'LastUpdated': 'Mon Apr 25 15:50:28 2011', 'Started': 'Not set',
'Priority': '0', 'Requestors': 'superuser@meme.com',
'AdminCc': '', 'Owner': 'Nobody', 'Told': 'Not set',
'TimeEstimated': '0', 'InitialPriority': '0', 'FinalPriority': '0',
'TimeWorked': '0', 'Subject': 'testing'}
>>>
```

Note 1: above output edited manually to avoid horizontal scrolling.

Note 2: Includes the Created and LastUpdated entries (-:*whose values contain colons*:-)

If you don't believe in blissfully ignoring things, you can do the splitlines first, and assert that the first line contains something like the expected heading, and that the second and last lines are empty.

Comment: @WSM: Supply such information in your QUESTION (edit it!), NOT in comments.

Comment: @John Machin By the way, your solution crashes on what seems to be the string that WSM wants to analyse, and that is in my answer, with a line withut any colon

Comment: @WSM: _"Supply such information in your QUESTION"_ YEAAAH ! He is right. Such an extraordinary idea, isn't ??!

Comment: @eyquem: re crashing: (1) how you can deduce the OP's desires from the current state of his example is hard to imagine (2) see the last sentence of my answer ("error checking")

Comment: @John Machin Well, if he needs your solution + error checking, it begins to ressemble to the first steps of creating a new mini-parser. Bty the way, excuse me but sometimes I don't read with super attention all the comments

Comment: @eyquem: I gave no indication that I was recommending a mini parser. Your "solution" ignores invalid input, which is worse than crashing.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like YAML. Have you tried [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/)?

```
>>> import yaml
>>> s = """id: 123414
... name: Peter
... message: bla bla
...   bla bla"""
>>> yaml.load(s)
{'message': 'bla bla bla bla', 'id': 123414, 'name': 'Peter'}
```

Comment: When i use yaml.load(mystring) i get ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here in "<string>" ...

Answer (score 0):

Given your poor question , we are driven to imagine what is the crucial problem, because I can't believe you had never heard about the string's method, so I think that you have no idea how to use them in this case.

There's certainly a way to get what you want with string's methods, I have an idea about that, but I prefer to turn directly to the regex tool, thinking that the difficulty is to catch a second part after a colon having newlines in it

```
import re

regx = re.compile ('(^[^:]+):((?:[^:]+\r?\n)*[^:]+)$',re.MULTILINE)

coloned = '''id: 123414
name: Peter
message: bla bla
bla bla
the end: of the text'''

print regx.findall(coloned)
```

gives

```
[('id', ' 123414'), ('name', ' Peter'), ('message', ' bla bla\nbla bla'), ('the end', ' of the text')]
```

.

### EDIT

So there was no difficulty in this "problem"

```
import re

regx = re.compile ('^([^:\n]+): *(.*?) *$',re.MULTILINE)

ch = ('RT/3.8.8 200 Ok\n'                                    '\n'
      'id: ticket/46863\n'      'Queue: customer-test\n'
      'Owner: Nobo:dy\n'        'Creator: young.park\n'
      'Subject: testing\n'      'Status: new\n'
      'Priority: 0\n'           'InitialPriority: 0\n'
      'FinalPriority: 0\n'      'Requestors: superuser@meme.com\n'
      'Cc:\nAdminCc:\n'         'Created: Mon Apr 25 15:50:27 2011\n'
      'Starts: Not set\n'       'Started: Not set\n'
      'Due: Not set\n'          'Resolved: Not set\n'
      'Told: Not set\n'         'LastUpdated: Mon Apr 25 15:50:28 2011\n'
      'TimeEstimated: 0\n'      'TimeWorked: 0\n'
      'TimeLeft: 0\n'           'CF.{Severity}: \n'           '\n')

print dict(regx.findall(ch))
print

s = 'id: 1234\nname: Peter\nmessage: foo bar zot\nmsg2: tee:hee\n'
print dict(regx.findall(s))
```

result

```
{'Due': 'Not set', 'Priority': '0', 'id': 'ticket/46863', 'Told': 'Not set', 'Status': 'new', 'Started': 'Not set', 'Requestors': 'superuser@meme.com', 'FinalPriority': '0', 'Resolved': 'Not set', 'Created': 'Mon Apr 25 15:50:27 2011', 'AdminCc': '', 'Starts': 'Not set', 'Queue': 'customer-test', 'TimeWorked': '0', 'TimeLeft': '0', 'Creator': 'young.park', 'Cc': '', 'LastUpdated': 'Mon Apr 25 15:50:28 2011', 'CF.{Severity}': '', 'Owner': 'Nobo:dy', 'TimeEstimated': '0', 'InitialPriority': '0', 'Subject': 'testing'}

{'message': 'foo bar zot', 'msg2': 'tee:hee', 'id': '1234', 'name': 'Peter'}
```

.

John Machin, I didn't mucked about this new regex, it took me one minute to rewrite, and it wouldn't have taken a lot more time at first if we wouldn't have to beg for the essential basic information needed to answer

Three remarks:

- if the input ever changes and a supplementary empty line appear anywhere among the others, your solution will crash, while my regex solution will continue to work well. Your solution needs to be completed with `if ':' in line`
- I compared the execution times:

  my regex sol **0.000152533352703** seconds , yours **0.000225727012791** ( + 48 % )

With `if ':' in line` added, it is slightly longer : 0.000246958761519 seconds   ( + 62 % )

Speed isn't important here, but in other applications, it is good to know that regexes are very fast (100 times faster than lxml, and 1000 faster than BeautifulSoup)

- you are a specialist of CSV format. A solution with StringIO and csv module 's functions could also be possible

Comment: @eyquem: a "key" containing a space e.g. "the end" is likely to be illegal. If so, we both need to suggest some error checking needs to be done in a subsequent step.

Comment: @John Machin a space before the first colon is likely to be illegal; and it is likely not to be illegal; and presence of another colon after the first one is likely not to be illegal, but maybe is likely to be illegal; and my supposition that there can be newlines in the second part is likely not to be true; and... and... You are right . But I gave me absolution in advance: _"Given your poor question , we are driven to imagine..."_ . If my solution isn't right , I will correct it if the questioner ever answers

Comment: @eyquem: also, (1) in reality it is likely that a newline embedded in the value is either forbidden or needs to be quoted/escaped somehow -- and probably ditto for a colon :-) (2) you leave unstripped spaces on keys and values (3) it would be nice if you explain the grammar that you assume -- regexes are much harder to reverse engineer than splitlines/split/strip.

Comment: @eyquem: and the likelihood that there is not an existing parser for a published API is rather low, too. I am merely listing out the many different paths that ones imagination may take :-)

Comment: @John Machin 1)Yes. Or no. Who knows ? 2) Yes, I choosed to avoid to get tired by all these kind of potential problem. Sometimes, I wish to write a short answer. :) 3) He has to learn, if he wish. The pattern isn't hard to understand in this case

Comment: @John Machin A parser... what is this obsession on stackoverflow.com to always want to find a parser to do the slightest tasks ??

Comment: @eyquem: It's trying to avoid people reinventing the wheel (which is usually NOT accompanied by reinventing the axle).

Comment: @John Machin Ah ah ah, very funny, the missing axle. So people never learn to build a little wheel, nor a little axle and they never understand, at least a little, what is under the hood of their magnificent 40 feet high wheels , of which they use only some percents

Comment: @eyquem: Consider a slight task like parsing a CSV file. Very simple, until your fields contain commas. Medium simple, until your fields contain quotes. Low simple, until your fields contain embedded newlines. Most folk have extreme difficulty *writing* a CSV file at the contains-quotes level of difficulty. Most people don't want to learn, they just want something to use, and they neither know nor care what percentage of functionality they are using.

Comment: @eyquem: Time to muck about with your regex again -- your current solution ignores two items in the actual example string; they have colons in the value part.

Comment: @John Machin My first solution have been written rapidly, I didn't imagine that second parts after colon could possibly have colon in them. In he other hand, I imagined that newlines could be in these second part, and I was wrong. We wouldn't have to make vain hypothesis to make up for the insufficience of information in the questions if the questions were more informative

Comment: @John Machin Yes , that is the impression I have: _" Most people don't want to learn, they just want something to use, and they neither know nor care what percentage of functionality they are using."_ . Doing so they don't learn basic tools that are polyvalent and they need to learn quantities of specialized tools that are over-powerful for the basic needs they have. Personnaly , I find the proliferation of applications as much a problem than a chance. And I'm not fond of learning various apps that overlap one on the other.

Comment: @John Machin By the way, I've just came accross that on the site: _" To get the original binary data back, strip out the 9 spaces with a regexp, strip off the 3 carriage returns at the end, and ...."_ for a certain REST answer

Comment: @eyquem: I see neither 9 spaces nor "3 carriage returns at the end" in the OP's sample data. What is the point that you are trying to make, if any?

Comment: @John Machin On the site, that is to say on (http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/REST) , there is this advice to use a regex for a particular task. Didn't say it is useful for us. In fact, to remove the 9 first characters of a line, there is no need to use regex; but that was to say that this site doesn't consider regexes with the same disapprobating eyes as you does.

Comment: @eyquem: So some whacker suggests using a regex to strip off 9 spaces from a string -- this is headline news? The whacker is being quoted as authoritative evidence of what?

Comment: @John Machin It is a faint argument, I recognize.

Answer (score 0):

[Examples](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/REST#Ticket) look like customized http messages (but they are not; it would be too simple); you could use [`rfc822.Message`](http://docs.python.org/library/rfc822.html#message-objects) to parse them:

```
import rfc822
from cStringIO import StringIO

# skip status line; read headers
m = rfc822.Message(StringIO(raw_text[raw_text.index('\n\n')+2:]))
```

Now you have access to individual headers:

```
>>> m.getheader('queue')
'customer-test'
>>> m.getrawheader('queue')
' customer-test\n'
>>> m.getheader('created')
'Mon Apr 25 15:50:27 2011'
>>> m.getdate('created')
(2011, 4, 25, 15, 50, 27, 0, 1, 0)
```

All headers:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dict(m.items()))
{'admincc': '',
 'cc': '',
 'cf.{severity}': '',
 'created': 'Mon Apr 25 15:50:27 2011',
 'creator': 'young.park',
 'due': 'Not set',
 'finalpriority': '0',
 'id': 'ticket/46863',
 'initialpriority': '0',
 'lastupdated': 'Mon Apr 25 15:50:28 2011',
 'owner': 'Nobody',
 'priority': '0',
 'queue': 'customer-test',
 'requestors': 'superuser@meme.com',
 'resolved': 'Not set',
 'started': 'Not set',
 'starts': 'Not set',
 'status': 'new',
 'subject': 'testing',
 'timeestimated': '0',
 'timeleft': '0',
 'timeworked': '0',
 'told': 'Not set'}
```