# How do I take info from a text file and put it into a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, class, function, file-io

I built a previous program that stores info to a txt file (yes I should have used a Db but haven't learned it well yet) anyway what I want to do is have a function or method that pulls that info from the file and stores it into a dictionary, all while possibly updating the text file/dict if something needs to change

The txt file is in this format

Name: John Doe

Num: 2485555555

City: Roseville

taking that info and storing it into something like this:

Friend = {'Name: ', 'John Doe', 'Num: ', '2485555555', 'City: ', 'Roseville'}

I figure I have to use the split method, Either way, I know this isn't the most practical way to do this but regardless learning how to do this could help down the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
friend = dict(line.split(":", 1) for line in open("file"))
```

This splits every line at the first colon to get a sequence of (key, value) pairs, and uses this sequence to initialise the dictionary.

To allow empty lines in your file, you could use

```
friend = dict(line.split(":", 1) for line in open("file") if line.strip())
```

Comment: thanks, can u explain a little of what this logic is saying so I understand it going forward and what is the 1 for?...

Comment: @Isov5: I added a short explanation.  The `1` means to only split at the first colon.  If there is only one colon on each line, it does not make any difference.

Comment: A google for "python split" reveals this as the first link http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split . The one is the maximum number of splits. This means that the first colon in the line must separate the key from value, but any other colons will be ignored.

Comment: Or, if you're looking for an excuse to use [dictionary comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Dict_comprehension): `{k:v for k, v in (l.split(':', 1) for l in open('file') if l.strip())}`. Definitely not the most legible, though.

Comment: it fails if line doesn't contain `':'`. You could use `line.partition(':')[::2]` to avoid it.

Comment: @ This question and answers are strangely identical to this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783417/using-python-to-parse-colon-delimited-string-to-an-object/5784360#comment-6630048)