# convert strings into python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a string which is as follows

```
my_string = '"sender" : "md-dgenie", "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6326. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!", "time" : "1439155575925", "name" : "John"'
```

I want to construct a dict from the above string. I tried something as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783417/using-python-to-parse-colon-delimited-string-to-an-object)

```
split_text = my_string.split(",")
for i in split_text :
    print i
```

then I got output as shown below:

```
"sender" : "md-dgenie"
 "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6632. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish
 my command!"     ### finds "," here and splits it here too.
 "time" : "1439155803426"
 "name" : "p"
```

I want output as key pair values of a dictionary as given below :

```
my_dict = { "sender" : "md-dgenie",
     "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6632. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!",
     "time" : "1439155803426",
     "name" : "p" }
```

Basically I want to skip that "," from the sentence and construct a dict. Any suggestions would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that is how you want to format `my_string`? I can't see how that can be a valid string, but then again, python is a weird language so there might be some obscure string formatting I don't know about.

Comment: Please correct the code you have posted. Your `my_string` is not a string, or anything else. It is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @TobLoef : Sorry! my bad! I forgot to single quotes to `my_string`. I have updated it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your string is *almost* already a python dict, so you could just enclose it in braces and then [evaluate it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) as such:

```
import ast
my_dict = ast.literal_eval('{{{0}}}'.format(my_string))
```

Comment: Oooh! How is this different from `eval` ?

Comment: @d-coder `ast.literal_eval` just parses the string and returns it if it evaluates to a literal. It doesn't actually execute it, so it's not vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Cool! It worked like a charm! I would give you badge for now because I think I can't up vote it. :P

Comment: @d-coder you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark (you might have to wait a bit first.)

Comment: Finally one upvote from my side and accepted your answer! :)

Comment: Good answer, though I have one small note: because we're adding curly braces, for this *particular* case the `.format()` method is a little clumsy. I would at least think about using `my_dict = ast.literal_eval('{' + my_string + '}')`.

Comment: @tzaman : I've many strings to parse out of which few throw error. "malformed string"

Answer (score 2):

```
my_string =' "sender" : "md-dgenie", "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6326. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!", "time" : "1439155575925", "name" : "John"'
import re
print dict(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"',my_string))
```

You can do it via finding `tuples` using `re.findall` and passing it to `dict`

Comment: Thanks! but I think I will go with @tzaman answer. I bad at regex!

Comment: There you go :) regex freaks me out!

Comment: I have one more question actually. Should I update this one or post another ? I want to know how store time in milliseconds to be stored in django models field ?

Comment: @d-coder if your new question is unrelated to parsing dictionary-like strings, post it separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could have also split on `",` and stripped the whitespace and `"`:

```
my_string = '"sender" : "md-dgenie", "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6326. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!", "time" : "1439155575925", "name" : "John"'
print(dict(map(lambda x:x.strip('" ') ,s.split(":")) for s in my_string.split('",')))

{'name': 'John', 'time': '1439155575925', 'sender': 'md-dgenie', 'text': 'your dudegenie code is 6326. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!'}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different take using dict comprehension, simpler regex and `zip(*[iter()]*n)`:

```
import re
my_string = '"sender" : "md-dgenie", "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6326. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!", "time" : "1439155575925", "name" : "John"'
{k:v for k,v in zip(*[iter(re.findall(r'"(.+?)"',my_string))]*2)}

{'text': 'your dudegenie code is 6326. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!', 'sender': 'md-dgenie', 'name': 'John', 'time': '1439155575925'}
```